# Initialize variables with Invoke-Expression

Tags: scripting, powershell

I'm trying to use Invoke-Expression to initialize a number of variables in my powershell script.

Here are the variables:

```
$saved_state_file = './var/mirmon.tmp';
$log_file = './var/mirmon.log';
$once_file = './var/once';
$plugin_dir = './libexec';
$verbose = 0;
$pause = 0;
$submit_method = 'ssh,http,smtp';
$http_user = $null
$http_pass = $null
```

Here is the function:

```
function read_config{
     $lasthost = 'Default'
     $return = @()
     $checks = @()
     $logs = @()
     foreach ($s in Get-Content $config_file){
         if(){...}
         else{
             $split = $s.Split('=',$option)
             $exp = "$" + $split[0] + '=' + '"' + $split[1] + '"'
             Invoke-Expression $exp
             }
      }
$return = $checks,$logs
return $return
```

}

And here is an example of what I´m trying to read:

```
verbose=2
http_user = user
http_pass = passw
smtp_host = test.some.com
log_file=/tmp/test.log
saved_state_file=/tmp/test.test.tmp
hung_time=20
plugin_dir=libexec
once_file=/tmp/once
submit_method=http
```

But there seems to be some problem with the scope of invoke-expression because the values are set in the read_config function but when that has finished running the values go back to their original values.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Gísli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you pretty much figured it out. It is a scope issue. When you are building your $exp, put $Script: in front of each variable name (so $Script:Verbose=2 instead of $verbose=2). That will force the scope for the variable to the script level.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain to me why this happens? All the variables are global so I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried: $Script:Verbose="2" and $Script:$Verbose="2" . 
Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: No, maybe I have. $script:verbose should force the scope to the script level. Let me check something

Comment: While I'm poking around, do this at the command prompt: Help about_scopes

Comment: I think I've got it. I had double quotes instead of single. This has been a root of too many problems in my script. The syntax is $Script:Verbose="2" like you said in the beginning.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it figured out. I generally *try* to make myself use '' instead of "" unless I absolutely have no choice. That being said, I've used "" in other languages that reflex still takes over and causes issues sometimes :)